# How to fix settings not working?

Tags: settings

I am currently using lenovo A1000 android phone. When I try to open it's settings, it just gives a blank white screen and nothing else. Other apps are also not working such as YouTube, Google play and night mode. Please tell me how can I resolve this issue soon before all the apps would stop working.

Comment: How did this start? Did you install some app or made some other changes? Usually a factory reset is recommended in such situations.